# ng-binding is not working but ng-model works

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ngmodel, ng-bind

I am learning to use Angular (1.3.10), I have two input fields that specify the suit and value for a hand of playing card. As you can see from the image below, when I try to hardcode the suit and value, the card shows up fine (one on the right). But when I use ng-model to bind it, the card_value is not displaying correctly although it is picked up by the browser. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div ng-app = "cards">
    <form>
        <div>
            <input ng-model = "card_value">
            <span>of</span>
            <input ng-model = "card_suit">
        </div>
    </form>

    <div>
        <p>Entered: {{card_value}} of {{card_suit}}</p>

        <!-- card.value is not binding up perfectly fine -->
        <card value = "{{card_value}}" suit = "{{card_suit}}"></card>
        <!--  -->

        <!-- this shows up perfectly fine -->
        <card value = "5" suit = "Clubs" ></card> 
        <!--  -->
    </div>
</div>
```

What I see being displayed:
[image]

Chrome inspector: the part that is highlighted is where ng-binding fails, should be 5
[image]

Comment: `this.pips` is assigned once on directive init and never modified later. To make the binding work it may be `this.getPip = getPip` and then `card.pip` in template may be replaced with `card.getPip()` (the same applies to this.display). The good thing is that the binding will work. The bad thing is that infinite digest may be caused because the binding can't be calculated efficiently. Any way, using ng-repeat for each pip will kill the performance very soon. It's ok if this is a demo but for real app you may want to use premade images for both look and performance.

Comment: @estus if I use pre made images then I am going to end up with 52 if statements. There has to be a better way

Comment: @estus would you mind to put your solution into code, it's a bit hard to follow

Comment: Sorry, don't have enough time for quality answer for now. The images can have suitable filenames that allow to substitute them via expression, it's the path of least resistance here, images offer best performance and look. Sure, it can be done in a lot of ways, e.g. input values may be watched with $scope.$watchCollection, and card's inner DOM is updated only on value changes with pure jQuery (that's where it is good), no pip bindings. The point is that ng-repeat affects the performance severely when being used incautiously , and optimizing Angular performance is a tough task for a beginner.

Comment: I would suggest to separate the question into smaller questions and address one issue at once with smaller pieces of code, there's a higher chance to get a good answer this way (don't forget to link to a bigger question to give a full perspective).

Answer (score 0):

[**ng-bind**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) has one-way data binding.

[**ng-model**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) is intended to be put inside of form elements and has two-way data binding 
You should use  `ng-bind`

```
  <div ng-bind-html="card_value"></div>
```

[`DEMO APP`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/wwaweb09/7/)

Comment: Why use this instead of ng-model?

Comment: @b11 you cannot use ng-model on a div , you can use on the following as per the documentation The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control) to a property on the scope using NgModelController, which is created and exposed by this directive.

Comment: in the example [ng-bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind), they still put a `ng-model` on the input and a `ng-bind` in the span element. How would I use it in my case, since card is a directive I created and not a div

Comment: as in I cannot do `<card ng-bind="card_value" ng-bind="card_suit"></card>`

Comment: Not working for me, the values are not binded with input boxes

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/wwaweb09/8/ give team viewer.i can check